# Python: Encoding issues?

Tags: python, html, encoding

in my HTML file, the word "Schilde­rung" looks normally and it doesn't seem to have an (encoding?) problem.
But when I copy the word, I get the following: "Schilde rung", and if I'd like to find out the length with python, I get 13 (instead of 12...).

What's the problem here, and how can I handle this?

Thanks a lot for any help!

EDIT:
At the moment, I use the following: `output.write(text.decode("utf-8"))`
This handles correctly all umlaut and other special char, but the above problem is still present. print(repr(txt)) gives: Schilde\xc2\xadrung 
How can we solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: show us `print(repr(the_word))`

Comment: Is there an umlaut or some other special char in the string?

Comment: Yes, there are umlaut and other special char in the string. So, I should handle the problem with "schilde rung" (which works with the printable or encode-solutions) BUT I should also keep the umlaut and other special char which are correctly represented...

Answer (score 1):

There is [U+00AD SOFT HYPHEN](http://codepoints.net/U+00ad) before `r` in the string:

```
>>> "Schilde­rung".decode('utf-8')
u'Schilde\xadrung'
```

To remove non-ascii characters:

```
>>> s = u'Schilde\xadrung'
>>> s.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode()
u'Schilderung'
>>> len(_)
11
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the problem.
Is there any way that I can check each word for this property? Because while applying this to all words, I get the error: "'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1162: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: @MarkF6: the error means that you are trying to encode bytes (that you should not do) instead of a Unicode string. If your input is a byte string that contains text in utf-8; you could call `.decode` to get Unicode string that has only ascii characters: `b"Schilde­rung".decode('ascii', 'ignore') ->
u'Schilderung'`

Comment: Ok, I did this, but what's about 'umlaut'?. If I do this, I lose all the 'umlaut'. (ä ö ü)

Comment: @MarkF6: If you don't mind non-ascii characters then just convert your input bytes to Unicode e.g. using `.decode('utf-8')` as shown in the very  first line in the answer and stop at that. If it is not enough then [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18654734/edit) to specify filtering rules i.e., what categories of characters to remove (blacklist), what to preserve (whitelist), etc. There are no universal rules; you need to choose what is appropriate in your case.

Comment: I added some specifications as comment and as EDIT to the initial post. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `"r"` isn't ASCII:

```
>>> u'Schilde­rung'
u'Schilde\xadrung'
```